# Python listing paragraph under certain number of characters

Tags: python

I am trying to display a paragraph in a certain way:

```
import textwrap

y = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
z = textwrap.wrap(y, width = 80)

for element in z:
    print(element)
```

This gives me a good paragraph which each line no more than 80 characters.
[image]
However, I also want to only list the first few sentences that as a whole do not exceed 250 characters. If each row is 80, that means something close but no more than the third row. Is it possible to do this task in the loop I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a slice, and then find the last period to cut off any partial sentences.

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

character_limit = 250
short_text = text[:character_limit]
short_text = short_text[:(short_text.rfind('.') + 1)]

>>> print('\n'.join(line for line in textwrap.wrap(short_text, width=80)))
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

You could do this in your loop, but it will be more complicated to figure out where the cutoff is.  Much easier to just clean up the text before printing.

Comment: works perfectly, and it is indeed simpler to clean the text before printing, thanks!